# Javascript - Distinguish between similar list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each list item is appended by this for loop. Imagine a list with three elements, for example. Two buttons in a row comprise each list element. The goal is to first hide all of the .second buttons by default. When a specific .first button is clicked, that specific .first button is hidden and that specific .second button is shown. By specific, I mean belonging to the same list element.

```
for (i=0; i<userLog.length; i++) {
      $('#modalChoices').append("<li id='modalItem'><input class='modalInput btn btn-primary first' type='button'> <input class='modalInput btn btn-success second' type='button'></li>");
    }

  // Hide all seconds by default.
  $('.second').hide();

  $('.first').on('click', function() {
    $('.first').hide();
    $('.second').show();
  });
```

We can hide all of the seconds and all of the firsts very easily. How do we distinguish between list items? Is there some 'this' selector that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner to fix this problem. `$(this)` refers to the `input.first` being clicked and `next()` is its adjacent `input.second`. It should be faster to use `next` than to use `siblings`.

```
$('.first').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().next('.second').show();
});
```

```js
  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      $('#modalChoices').append("<li id='modalItem'><input class='modalInput btn btn-primary first' value='first' type='button'> <input class='modalInput btn btn-success second' type='button' value='second'></li>");
    }

  // Hide all seconds by default.
  $('.second').hide();

  $('.first').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().next('.second').show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalChoices"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)` selector to hide first button and use `$(this).siblings('.second')` selector to show second button for that specific `li`.

```
$('.first').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.second').show();
});
```

Please check below snippet for better undertanding.

```js
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
  $('#modalChoices').append("<li id='modalItem'><input class='modalInput btn btn-primary first' value='first' type='button'> <input class='modalInput btn btn-success second' type='button' value='second'></li>");
}

// Hide all seconds by default.
$('.second').hide();

$('.first').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.second').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalChoices"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event callbacks always have the context of the target element. So you can get a pointer to them using `this`. Then use the `.siblings` function to get any adjacent items, in this case `.second`.

Note: it's always a good idea to not resolve selectors repeatedly, and to use a context in your selectors, like I've done here with the `modalChoices` var.

```
    var modalChoices = $('#modalChoices');

    for (i = 0; i < userLog.length; i++) {
          modalChoices.append("<li id='modalItem'><input class='modalInput btn btn-primary first' type='button'> <input class='modalInput btn btn-success second' type='button'></li>");
    }

    // Hide all seconds by default. 
    $('.second', modalChoices).hide();

    $('.first', modalChoices).on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide().siblings(".second").show();
    });
```